# GD for logistic regression isn't stable. Why?

Tags: machine-learning, python, logistic-regression

Here's my (incomplete) implementation for linear regression using GD:

```
from enum import Enum
import numpy as np
from math import exp

class GDType(Enum):
  GD = 1
  SGD = 2

class LogisticRegression:
  def __init__(self, gd_type=GDType.GD, learning_rate=0.1, num_iterations=1000):
    self.gd_type = gd_type
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.num_iterations = num_iterations


  def __odds(self, x, b):
    return exp(b.dot(x)) / float(exp(1 + b.dot(x)))

  def __gd_step(self, X, y):

    grad = np.zeros(self.p)

    for j in range(self.p):
      for i in range(self.m):
        grad[j] += self.__odds(X[i], self.b) - y[i]
      grad[j] *= X[i, j]

    return grad 

  def __gd(self, X, y):
    for i in range(self.num_iterations):
      dl = self.__gd_step(X, y)
      self.b -= (self.learning_rate / float(self.m)) * dl
      print(self.b)

  def fit(self, X, y):
    X = np.column_stack((np.ones(X.shape[0]).T, X)) # 1's column for the bias
    self.m = X.shape[0]
    self.p = X.shape[1]
    self.b = np.zeros(self.p)  
    self.__gd(X, y)
    print(self.b)
```

I'm testing it on the iris data, as follows:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]
y = (iris.target != 0) * 1

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)
```

The problem is that the coefficients are getting larger and larger instead of converging. Why?

I doubled checked (correct me if wrong) and it seems to me that `__gd_step` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation seems not correct. For example:

(1) in your `__gd_step()` function, the line

```
grad[j] *= X[i, j]
```

which uses the index `i`, is outside your for loop: `for i in range(self.m)`.

(2) in your `__odds()` function, the denominator `exp(1 + b.dot(x))` seems incorrect. `1` should be outside of `exp()`.